# (Django) Cannot update custom profile

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

So I'm trying to update the user's info in an extended update, but it worked before I added the rest, but now it won't work I've tried going back still nothing.

So it does send the post but it cannot validate it.

#### Html

```
<form action="{% url 'userprofileupdate' logged_in_user.pk %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
https://pastebin.com/vMw6AEai (only Pastebin because of its a lot of code)
```

#### Views.py

```
@login_required
def userprofileupdate(request, user_pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
            user.extendeduser.nickname = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            user.extendeduser.postal_code = form.cleaned_data.get('postal_code')
            user.extendeduser.phone_number = form.cleaned_data.get('phone_number')
            user.extendeduser.emergency_number = form.cleaned_data.get('emergency_number')
            user.extendeduser.birthdate = form.cleaned_data.get('birthdate')
            user.extendeduser.languages = form.cleaned_data.get('languages')
            user.extendeduser.drivers_licence = form.cleaned_data.get('drivers_licence')
            user.extendeduser.tshirt = form.cleaned_data.get('tshirt')
            user.extendeduser.special_considerations = form.cleaned_data.get('special_considerations')
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, "Your profile has been updated!")
            return redirect('usersettings', user_pk=request.user.pk)

    messages.error(request, 'Error: please update your settings if you want to update them')
    return redirect('usersettings', user_pk=request.user.pk)
```

#### forms.py

```
class UpdateProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    postal_code = forms.CharField(max_length=10, required=True)
    phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=16, required=True)
    emergency_number = forms.CharField(max_length=16, required=True)
    birthdate = forms.DateField(required=False)
    languages = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False)
    drivers_licence = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False)
    tshirt = forms.ChoiceField(required=False)
    special_considerations = forms.CharField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'birthdate', 'phone_number', 'emergency_number', 'postal_code', 'languages', 'drivers_licence', 'tshirt', 'special_considerations',)
```

Comment: "<form xaction".  I guess you meant "<form action"

Comment: @wm3ndez Yes it was a miss addin from my side, but the thing as I wrote it does not take it as a post request once pressed submit

Answer (score 0):

You didn't save the extendeduser object.

```
user.extendeduser.save()
```

Comment: No need for that i added in the models app so once user model is updated the extendeduser model gets automatically saved to

but the thing as i wrote it does not take it as a post request once pressed submit

Comment: So it does send it but it cannot validate the form.

Comment: Well, if the form is not valid you should display the errors rather than redirecting to another page and hiding them.

Comment: Well even tho I do that remove all returns it still doesn't give a result

Comment: What does "it doesn't give a result" mean? What does the code look like now and what do you see? Why can't you use the documented pattern for views that process forms?

Comment: (1)It doesn't give a proper error other than saying no HttpResponse.(2)
The code is like above tho the view are not with HttpResponse this time tho (3) Are there a documented pattern? I've been using this for some time now. please consider its Django v1.11

Comment: Well obviously if you remove all the returns then the view is not going to work, a view must return a response. The proper pattern for forms, as I said above, is to redisplay the template with the invalid form when it fails validation, not to redirect away. That way the user sees what is wrong and has the chance to correct it. This is [fully explained](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#the-view) in the docs.

Comment: Well, that is basically what I'm doing, I have another view where the form is sent from and then coming to the update view. but the problem is that IT won't VALIDATE! WHY THO I CANNOT SEE WHY it gives nothing in the terminal it gives no errors it just go past it,

Comment: **You are not showing the invalid form in the template**. If you did, you would *know* why it will not validate, because *it would tell you*.

Comment: I do show the form in the template i have a production with the same method but not so many fields and its updating fine let take it to a chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166378/discussion-between-meicki-jeldal-and-daniel-roseman).

Answer (score 0):

1-First run ./manage.py shell
2-Run all the update user command in shell to verify error is not there.
3-If error is not there post the error logs of ./manage.py runserver then i will be in better position to answer you problem accurately.

Comment: Also its does go to the post but the post cannot be validated i just found out why tho?

Answer (score 0):

So the thing I missed was that I used manytomany and foreign keys in the model, and didn't see that there where a field called ModelChoiceField and ModelMultipleChoiceField with that was the case it didn't work. so I basically change my form this and then it worked

#### Form.py

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField, ModelMultipleChoiceField    
class TshirtChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.description

class DriversLicenceCategoriesMultipleChoiceField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.category

class LanguageMultipleChoiceField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.name

class UpdateProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    birthdate = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y'],required=False)
    phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=16, required=True)
    emergency_number = forms.CharField(max_length=16, required=False)
    postal_code = forms.CharField(max_length=10, required=True)
    languages = LanguageMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Language.objects.all(),required=False)
    drivers_licence = DriversLicenceCategoriesMultipleChoiceField(queryset=DriversLicenceCategories.objects.all(),required=False)
    tshirt = TshirtChoiceField(queryset=TShirt.objects.all(),required=False)
    special_considerations = forms.CharField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'birthdate', 'phone_number', 'emergency_number', 'postal_code', 'languages', 'drivers_licence', 'tshirt', 'special_considerations',)
```